# Adjust keyboard options on first page on tablets and mobiles

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html

I have seen on some websites that when you fill in a form field, the keyboard shows/hides certain characters on the first page of the touch keyboard.

This could be used for a number of uses:

- If you were on an online HTML editor for mobile devices, you would not like to keep on searching for the '<' and '>' on the keyboard in all the different pages. You would preferably like them on the first page for easy access.
- If you were coding in python and using comments on an online editor then you would like the '#' in easy reach.
- I have even seen some websites put the '@' symbol on the first page in an email address field.

Do you know what framework I would use to customise the keyboard like this? Is it JavaScript, jQuery, or just plain CSS and HTML? Is it different for Apple/Android?

Comment: It usually is triggered by the browser on the OS which interpret an e.g. <input type='email' ...` as an email address and therefore shows the `@` on the first keyboard page.  Check html5 semantics for more details.

Comment: Is there another way of doing it with JavaScript / HTML / CSS

Comment: `<input type='email'` is html. I am not aware of CSS/javascript options to trigger this kind of functionality. Beware that CSS options might be browser specific. Like the `-moz-keys`.

Comment: Can you customise the `input type` with CSS? Maybe look at the default settings and change them?